# How to resolve error: EACCES: permission denied when installing Polymer 2.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

Running into an issue trying to install Polymer 2.0
I have node v 8.9.1 installed as well as bower 1.8.2.

To install polymer 2.0, I used the following statements directly from the [Polymer install docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/start/install-2-0):

```
npm install -g polymer-cli
```

However, I keep running into this error and don't know how to get around it.

```
npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.2: ...psst! Your project can stop working at any moment because its dependencies can change. Prevent this by migrating to Yarn: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update! 
npm WARN deprecated @types/assert@0.0.29: See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/12826
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/polymer
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/local/bin/polymer'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/local/bin/polymer'
npm ERR!   cause: 
npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/local/bin/polymer'
npm ERR!      errno: -13,
npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!      path: '/usr/local/bin/polymer' },
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink \'/usr/local/bin/polymer\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/bin/polymer' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jdk588/.npm/_logs/2017-12-04T14_51_46_451Z-debug.log
```

I've tried running the command with sudo and still no luck.

Comment: Show us the results of running `sudo ls -l /usr/local/bin/polymer` and `sudo ls -ld /usr/local/bin`

Comment: Would also be useful to know what terminal you are using? Windows 10 Bash by chance?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure this is the solution but here below from the [Polymer page](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/tools/node-support) :

**What versions of Node.js do we support?**

We support all "Current" and "Active LTS" releases of Node.js according to the Node.js Long Term Support Release Schedule, but not "Maintenance" releases.

This means we will support from two to three semver major versions of Node.js, depending on where we are in the Node LTS schedule. **Currently we support 6.x and 7.x.**

**So, try to downgrade the Node ver. to 6.x or 7.x**

Comment: Both 6.x and 8.x are Active LTS currently. https://github.com/nodejs/Release

Also, the errors provided point to permission issues, which are common in Windows.